# How to apply exponents to a built list in racket

Tags: scheme, racket

[image]So I know how to build a list in racket using, build-list

for example:

```
(build-list 2 add1) => (list 1 2)
```

But if I wanted to apply exponents to the list, where it ends at a certain number, how would I go about doing so.

For example:
the exponent 3, it will start at 0 and end at 3,  applying it to 1 and 2 from the built list.

```
1^0 * 1^1 * 1^2 * 1^3 
2^0 * 2^1 * 2^2 * 2^3
```

Roughly what I have.

```
(define (list-of-numbers m n)
(apply * (build-list (get m) (lambda (n) (expt n n)))))

  (define (get m)
    (build-list m add1))
```

Output should be:

```
(list-of-numbers 2 3) ⇒ (list 1 64)

1 × 1 × 1 × 1 = 1 
1 × 2 × 4 × 8 = 64
```

Comment: Yes my example is correct. N builds the exponent list to whatever n is from 0. M is the base starting from 1 to m. The exponent n is applied to M.

Comment: I would love to use range but I am not allowed to unfortunately.

Comment: Are `map`, `lambda`, and `apply` allowed?

Comment: Yes they are allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using `build-list` could begin by building a list of `m` elements:

```
(build-list m add1)
```

Here, `(build-list 2 add1)` --> `(1 2)`

Next, one could `map` over the list with `build-list` again, to construct a list of lists. We will need a procedure to apply to the list, e.g. `(1 2)`, that will construct a list from each element. Note that each element should transform to a list of `n+1` elements (in the case of `list-of-numbers 2 3` we have `n == 3`):

```
(lambda (x) (build-list (add1 n) some-procedure))
```

When this procedure is applied to an element from `(1 2)`, we should get a list like `(1 1 1 1)`, or `(1 2 4 8)`. To this end, `some-procedure` will be called on a number in the range `[0, n]`. What `some-procedure` needs to do is to take its number from the first list (`x` in the above `lambda` expression), and raise it to the power of its number from the second list (the number in the range `[0, n]`). So, now can write `some-procedure` as:

```
(lambda (y) (expt x y))
```

Here, `x` is taken from the first `lambda` expression, and `y` is taken from the range `[0, n]` provided by `build-list`. Now we need to `map` this compound `lambda` expression over the first list we built:

```
(map (lambda (x) (build-list (add1 n) (lambda (y) (expt x y))))
     (build-list m add1))
```

If we were to test the result of the above mapping with inputs of 2 and 3 for `m` and `n`, respectively, we would get:

```
'((1 1 1 1) (1 2 4 8))
```

All that is left is to `apply` multiplication to the sublists here; again, we can `map` a `lambda` expression that uses `apply` on each of the sublists, leaving us with a list of results:

```
(define (list-of-numbers m n)
  (map (lambda (s) (apply * s))
       (map (lambda (x) (build-list (add1 n) (lambda (y) (expt x y))))
            (build-list m add1))))
```

Here is some sample output:

```
scratch.rkt> (list-of-numbers 2 3)
'(1 64)
scratch.rkt> (list-of-numbers 3 3)
'(1 64 729)
scratch.rkt> (list-of-numbers 3 2)
'(1 8 27)
```

> ### Is there anything I can use instead of apply?

Instead of using `apply`, one could use `map` again, with a `lambda` expression that applies `foldl` along with multiplication to the sublists:

```
(define (list-of-numbers-2 m n)
  (map (lambda (x) (foldl * 1 x))
       (map (lambda (x) (build-list (add1 n) (lambda (y) (expt x y))))
            (build-list m add1))))
```

Works the same as before:

```
scratch.rkt> (list-of-numbers-2 2 3)
'(1 64)
scratch.rkt> (list-of-numbers-2 3 3)
'(1 64 729)
scratch.rkt> (list-of-numbers-2 3 2)
'(1 8 27)
```

Comment: Thank you, this really helped me understand clearly :)). Thank you for being really helpful. :)

Comment: Any time, and happy Scheming ;)

Comment: Is there anything I can use instead of apply?

Comment: @loren -- how about using `map` with `foldl` instead?

Comment: Yes how would I do so. Can you demonstrate?

Comment: @loren -- done. Did you find that `apply` is not acceptable, or were you just curious?

Comment: Yes apply was not acceptable, but thank you for helping. :)

Answer (score 1):

For each of these you have the exponents 0..3, which you can get with `build-list 4`

```
> (build-list 4 (lambda (n) n))
(list 0 1 2 3)
```

Then you can put the `expt` call inside the lambda

```
> (build-list 4 (lambda (n) (expt 2 n)))
(list 1 2 4 8)
```

If you want to multiply the elements of the list you can use `apply *`

```
> (apply * (build-list 4 (lambda (n) (expt 2 n))))
64
```

Comment: Thank you Alex. If i wanted the user to enter the number for the built list and exponent , how would I do so. In play of build-list 4. I understand that I have to define another variable for example m.

Comment: I have used your feed back, but I am still stuck, my code is above.